# SQL Query Performance Optimization on half million records

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I am working with the database which is having five tables, and I have created an SP that gives an overview of all five tables. The sum of all 5 tables doesn't reach half a million records but SP taking 20 - 50 seconds to just give me counts. I have created indexes but still no luck.

Below is my SP:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_TableCounts]

@TotalRecords   int output,
@TodayRecords   int output,

@New    int output,
@Modified   int output,
@Deleted    int output,
@DeletedToday   int output,

@TotalError int output,

@Table1NewRecords   int output,
@Table1ModifiedRecords  int output,
@Table1DeletedRecords   int output,
@Table1ErrorRecords int output,

@Table2NewRecords   int output,
@Table2ModifiedRecords  int output,
@Table2DeletedRecords   int output,
@Table2ErrorRecords int output,

@Table3NewRecords   int output,
@Table3ModifiedRecords  int output,
@Table3DeletedRecords   int output,
@Table3ErrorRecords int output,

@Table4NewRecords   int output,
@Table4ModifiedRecords  int output,
@Table4DeletedRecords   int output,
@Table4ErrorRecords int output,

@Table5NewRecords   int output,
@Table5ModifiedRecords  int output,
@Table5DeletedRecords   int output,
@Table5ErrorRecords int output

as
begin

SELECT @TotalRecords =
(select count(1) from Table1)
+
(select count(1) from Table2)
+
(select count(1) from Table3)
+
(select count(1) from Table4)
+
(select count(1) from Table5)



SELECT @TodayRecords =
(select count(1) from Table1 where Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))
+
(select count(1) from Table2 where Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))
+
(select count(1) from Table3 where Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))
+
(select count(1) from Table4 where Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))
+
(select count(1) from Table5  where Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))


SELECT @New =
(select count(1) from Table1 where RecordStatus = 1)
+
(select count(1) from Table2 where RecordStatus = 1)
+
(select count(1) from Table3 where RecordStatus = 1)
+
(select count(1) from Table4 where RecordStatus = 1)
+
(select count(1) from Table5  where RecordStatus = 1)

SELECT @Modified =
(select count(1) from Table1 where RecordStatus = 2)
+
(select count(1) from Table2 where RecordStatus = 2)
+
(select count(1) from Table3 where RecordStatus = 2)
+
(select count(1) from Table4 where RecordStatus = 2)
+
(select count(1) from Table5  where RecordStatus = 2)

SELECT @Deleted =
(select count(1) from Table1 where (RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B')))
+
(select count(1) from Table2 where (RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B')))
+
(select count(1) from Table3 where (RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B')))
+
(select count(1) from Table4 where (RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B')))
+
(select count(1) from Table5  where (RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B'))) 

SELECT @DeletedToday = 
(select count(1) from Table1 where (RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B')) and Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))
+
(select count(1) from Table2 where (RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B')) and Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))
+
(select count(1) from Table3 where (RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B')) and Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))
+
(select count(1) from Table4 where (RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B')) and Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))
+
(select count(1) from Table5  where (RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B')) and Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))


SELECT @TotalError =
(select count(1) from Table1 where RecordStatus = 4 and ([Status] != 'A')  and ([Status] != 'B'))
+
(select count(1) from Table2 where RecordStatus = 4 and ([Status] != 'A')  and ([Status] != 'B'))
+
(select count(1) from Table3 where RecordStatus = 4 and ([Status] != 'A')  and ([Status] != 'B'))
+
(select count(1) from Table4 where RecordStatus = 4 and ([Status] != 'A')  and ([Status] != 'B'))
+
(select count(1) from Table5  where RecordStatus = 4 and ([Status] != 'A')  and ([Status] != 'B'))


SELECT @Table1NewRecords = (select count(1) from Table1 where RecordStatus = 1)
SELECT @Table1ModifiedRecords = (select count(1) from Table1 where RecordStatus = 2)
SELECT @Table1DeletedRecords = (select count(1) from Table1 where RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B'))
SELECT @Table1ErrorRecords = (select count(1) from Table1 where RecordStatus = 4 and ([Status] != 'A')  and ([Status] != 'B'))

SELECT @Table2NewRecords = (select count(1) from Table2 where RecordStatus = 1)
SELECT @Table2ModifiedRecords = (select count(1) from Table2 where RecordStatus = 2)
SELECT @Table2DeletedRecords = (select count(1) from Table2 where RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B'))
SELECT @Table2ErrorRecords = (select count(1) from Table2 where RecordStatus = 4 and ([Status] != 'A')  and ([Status] != 'B'))

SELECT @Table3NewRecords = (select count(1) from Table3 where RecordStatus = 1)
SELECT @Table3ModifiedRecords = (select count(1) from Table3 where RecordStatus = 2)
SELECT @Table3DeletedRecords = (select count(1) from Table3 where RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B'))
SELECT @Table3ErrorRecords = (select count(1) from Table3 where RecordStatus = 4 and ([Status] != 'A')  and ([Status] != 'B'))

SELECT @Table4NewRecords = (select count(1) from Table4 where RecordStatus = 1)
SELECT @Table4ModifiedRecords = (select count(1) from Table4 where RecordStatus = 2)
SELECT @Table4DeletedRecords = (select count(1) from Table4 where RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B'))
SELECT @Table4ErrorRecords = (select count(1) from Table4 where RecordStatus = 4 and ([Status] != 'A')  and ([Status] != 'B'))

SELECT @Table5NewRecords = (select count(1) from Table5 where RecordStatus = 1)
SELECT @Table5ModifiedRecords = (select count(1) from Table5 where RecordStatus = 2)
SELECT @Table5DeletedRecords = (select count(1) from Table5 where RecordStatus = 3 or ([Status] = 'A')  or ([Status] = 'B'))
SELECT @Table5ErrorRecords = (select count(1) from Table5 where RecordStatus = 4 and ([Status] != 'A')  and ([Status] != 'B'))

end
```

Any suggestions on how can I make the structure of my query better? I believe this structure is very poor.

**UPDATE**

---

- Also, I can't use lots of indexes as tables have a huge amount of
  update/insert/delete transactions after every second, and having too
  many indexes affect SLA.

---

Comment: What version of sql server? Run `select @@version`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Edition on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0

Comment: This query has a *lot* of problems, including scanning all the data multiple times. `where Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))` is simply a bug. What is `RecTimestamp`? Unless it's a date-related type, it's a serious design bug. Applying a function on a field means any indexes built using the original field values can't be used

Comment: Perhaps you should first figure out which part of your query is taking the longest amount of time and focus on that.

Comment: You need to break this down into smaller chunks. You are needlessly scanning each table multiple times, so immediately you can have a 5x improvement using 'sum()' and 'case()'. Have you examined the execution plan to see if your indexes are used?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos RecTimestamp basically a DateTime in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss format. However, from the beginning it is stored in varchar datatype so I can not change it now.

Comment: @sTTu I need them in different output parameters as on the front end I need to show each output in a different block/section so can not apply sum altogether.

Comment: Do textual comparison (like) with date part of RecTimestamp then, without converting - should be able to use index. What about different parameters - you can replace conditional `count() ... where condition` with `sum(case when condition then 1 else 0 end)`, this way you need to query each table only once.

Comment: Using `sp_` as a prefix will also be a performance hit. `sp_` as a prefix is reserved by Microsoft, for **S**pecial **P**rocedures, and should *not* be used for user objects.

Comment: Getting things like these counts from all different sorts of tables sounds like a design flaw as well. Especially when they all share the columns `RecordStatus`, `Status` and `RecTimestamp`. Looks like the database's design needs fixing before you even begin to fix the Procedure.

Comment: If `RecTimestamp` was a date and was indexed, you could do a pretty fast `RecTimestamp >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime) AND RecTimestamp < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AS datetime)`

Comment: @Larnu each table has other different columns. Only these are commons.

Comment: Also I can't use lots of indexes as tables have huge amount of update/insert/delete transactions after every second and having too many indexes effect SLA.

Answer (score 1):

There are many improvements you can make here, one of the biggest will be replacing each block of 5 repeating selects like so:

```
select
    @Table1NewRecords=Sum (case when recordstatus=1 then 1 else 0 end)
    @Table1ModifiedRecords=Sum (case when recordstatus=2 then 1 else 0 end)
    @Table1DeletedRecords=Sum (case when recordstatus=3 or [Status] in( 'A','B') then 1 else 0 end)
    @Table1ErrorRecords=Sum (case when recordstatus=4 and [Status] != 'A'  and [Status] != 'B' then 1 else 0 end)
from table1
where recordstatus between 1 and 4
```

And like above, where you're repeatedly scanning the same tables for different counts, you can hit the table only once and use a conditional sum to count the relevant rows.

You should also consider adding the function on RecTimestamp as a permanent column and indexing on it as `where Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103)` is not sargable and will force a scan of each table. This is because SQL first has to perform the calcluation on every row before it can know if it qualifies.

Additionally, as you're using sql 2017 then `batchmode` can improve the performance of these types of queries, you will need to review the execution plans and check the execution mode of the various operators.

Comment: I can't use lots of indexes as tables have a huge amount of update/insert/delete transactions after every second and having too many indexes affect SLA

Answer (score 0):

Some of those queries won't be able to use indexes even if those indexes exist due to the data type conversions done on the filter columns in the where clause predicate.

E.g. things like *"where Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))"* will result in a full table scan, even if there is an index in "RecTimestamp".

Comment: How can I overcome this issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: The first example in @SQLpro's answer should solve that part.

Answer (score 0):

Two significant modification can be made to speed up your queries.

1. as KrsitoferA says replace the

   Convert(date,CONVERT(datetime,RecTimestamp,120),103) = Convert(date,GETDATE(),103))

...by:

```
WHERE  RecTimestamp >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
  AND  RecTimestamp < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Which will by sargable and use an index.

Second, inside the table1..5 add some persistant computed columns as:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 
   ADD STATUS_4_AND_A_OR_B 
   AS CAST(CASE WHEN RecordStatus = 3 or [Status] = 'A'  or [Status] = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) PERSISTED;

ALTER TABLE Table1 
   ADD STATUS_4_NOT_A_NOT_B 
   AS CAST(CASE WHEN  RecordStatus = 4 and [Status] <> 'A'  and [Status] <> 'B' THEN 1 ELSE O END AS BIT) PERSISTED;
```

3. create indexes:

   X1 : (RecordStatus )
   X2 : (STATUS_4_AND_A_OR_B)
   X3 : (STATUS_4_AND_A_OR_B, RecTimestamp)
   X4 : (STATUS_4_NOT_A_NOT_B)

And enjoy

Comment: I don't know why I cannot have the code enlightment in my post for the 3rd part... I try several times...